# Extracting "About this item" from Amazon Product Advertising API 5.0

Tags: python, amazon-product-api

I am working with API for Amazon product advertising.

I am using the following code:

```
pip install python-amazon-paapi --upgrade
pip install amightygirl.paapi5-python-sdk
from amazon.paapi import AmazonAPI
amazon = AmazonAPI(KEY, SECRET, TAG, COUNTRY)
product = amazon.get_product('B01N5IB20Q')
print(product.title)
```

I am unable to figure out how to extract short description from `About this item` section of products. Can someone help me what field I should be asking for?

Edit: I am using above code as an example, I just want to know what field in general can be used to extract "About this item" information.

Comment: SO might not be the appropriate place to ask. Instead ask the project maintainers.

Comment: You could iterate and print all the product attributes instead of only the title ... Or just attach a debugger after getting the product and inspect the attributes